# Which statistic to choose - biased or unbiased?

Tags: sampling, bias, unbiased-estimator

In a book on introductory statistics, there is a question that goes like this:

> If two statistics are available for estimating a population
>   characteristic, under what circumstances might you choose a biased
>   statistic over an unbiased statistic?

The answer provided in the back of the book is as follows:

> A biased statistic might be chosen over an unbiased statistic if the
>   bias is not too large, and the standard error of the biased statistic
>   is much smaller than the standard error of the unbiased statistic. In
>   this case, the observed value of the biased statistic might be closer
>   to the actual value than the value of an unbiased statistic.

My question is if the biased statistic is closed to the actual value and has a small standard error, then why it is considered as "biased" in the first place?

Comment: A biased estimator can have a smaller *mean square error* (MSE) than that of an unbiased estimator, whence it is taken as better in the MSE sense.

Comment: at this point, MSE is not yet introduced in the book. So, with this restriction, does the answer still makes sense?

Comment: The answer you quoted precisely uses the MSE criterion. MSE is variance + bias.

Comment: Consider two digital thermometers (say), A and B.  Due to manufacturing defects, A is always wrong by some small fixed-but-unknown amount (say on the order of 0.1 degrees).  Thus, A is biased.  Due to cheap components, B gives inconsistent readings, always adding or subtracting a random amount in the range 0 to 5 degrees, though the long-run average of its readings is in fact correct.  Thus, B in unbiased; but you would probably rather use A.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks for letting me know about MSE. I will get back to this question after learning about it.

Comment: @Creosote your analogy makes much more sense to me than equations and stats buzzwords. Thanks